# Direction of rotation in CSS Animation\Transformation

Tags: css, animation, transform

I'm trying to understand CSS animations and I'm running into the following issue:

I've got a simple div with animation attached to it in CSS, like below:

```
<div id="learn">LEARN</div>

#learn {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    animation: test1 5s ease-in 2s infinite;
}
```

**Case 1:**

```
@keyframes test1 {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(179deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(357deg);
    }
}
```

**Case 2 (the 0% transform is split into 90+89 deg instead of 179):**

```
@keyframes test1 {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(90deg) rotate(89deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(357deg);
    }
 }
```

Why is the first case rotating clockwise and the second case rotating counter clockwise?

Comment: I believe it rotates in the direction that takes the smallest angle between the start and end values of a circle (with 357 obviously being -3 degrees)

Comment: I am not sure if I got your point. The smaller angle in both cases is in the clockwise direction.

Comment: What is the browser that you are using and its version? I am on Chrome v38 (old but still) and both versions rotate clockwise.

Comment: I use firefox . Its the latest.

Answer (score 4):

This might just be a bug with rotation transforms, which I'll address after some background.

**Background**

First off, the way rotations are *supposed* to work is with relation to a circle.  If you specify a number of degrees, that will place the element in the position dictated by a how much rotation the degrees specify.  When not animating a rotation, there are many ways to represent the element's placement.  Code Uniquely is half-right in their comment in that the placement of 357 degrees and -3 degrees is the same, but when animating, they're very different.  Going from 0 degrees to -3 degrees is a small counter-clockwise rotation, whereas going from 0 degrees to 357 degrees is a large clockwise rotation.

**Findings**

What you've found seems to ignore this calculation (in both Firefox and Chrome from what I've tested out).  From what I'm seeing, combining `rotate` transforms effectively reverses the direction that the rotation *should* be going in, even if you're combining with a `0deg` rotation:

```
transform: rotate(90deg); //rotates clockwise
transform: rotate(0deg) rotate(90deg); //rotates counter-clockwise
```

It seems that you can fix this by "combining" the rotation transforms in both animation steps:

```
// this performs a clockwise rotation
@keyframes test3 {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg) rotate(90deg);
    }    
    100% {
        transform: rotate(0deg) rotate(357deg);
    }
}
```

Finally, it seems that the number of "combinations" matters.  If you combine 2 rotations in one step, but 3 in another, the unexpected behavior occurs:

```
// rotates counter-clockwise since there are unequal rotation transforms
@keyframes test4 {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg) rotate(0deg) rotate(90deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(0deg) rotate(357deg);
    }
}
```

**Conclusion**

This likely isn't the greatest answer, but combining rotations like this just doesn't appear to be documented anywhere.  I would suggest not combining the same `rotate` transforms (you can still combine `rotateX` and `rotateY` without this weirdness) and stick with the sum of the degree values.

In case anyone finding this explanation wants to perhaps find out more about this behavior than I have, here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8vx5Lw8/) with the examples above as a starting point.

Comment: Actually I observed this while trying to understand a "floating in water" behavior achieved by multiple transformations. The following keyframe gives a very good "floating" feel, with very few css lines. I have no clue how !!!. 0% { transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(0) translateY(1px) rotate(0deg) } 100% { transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(0) translateY(1px) rotate(-360deg) }                I can understand the downward drift ....but not sure how it gets that left to right movement

Comment: That's a pretty neat trick actually.  The `transforms` in CSS3 have an interesting mechanic of applying the `rotate` to a different pivot point depending on the previous translation (so basically the order of the parts of a transform plays a big part in what the final animation looks like). Check out this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8vx5Lw8/1/) to see what I mean.  The 1st div rotates on its center, the 2nd rotates based on the `translateX`, the 3rd based on `translateX` and `translateY`, and the final one is the 3rd without the extra movement (tested in Chrome)

Comment: Nice to see this. But I guess the difference in behavior between div2 and div3 is because the "net" rotation of 100% state in div2 is 360deg giving it the rotation on its own axis also. The net rotation of 100% in div3 is 0deg. So no axial rotation. But then again why are the "whole div" following the spiral path to reach end state ?

Comment: Having four classes of "wind directecion" (east, south, west, north) with corresponding css classes that could be changed by the user by a certain keyboard stroke made the rotation correctly for three steps untill it encountered the step from 270deg to 0deg which it performs counter clockwise by default (Chrome as of today). By adding transform: rotate(360) before rotate(0) it rotates as desired. Thanx for the tip!